# Undefined negotiate for SignalR connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I want to make the connection for SignalR.
However, the connection cannot be established and there is an error for undefined negotiate. Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Thank you in advance.
Here is the code for the startup file.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
```

Here is the code for the connection

```
$(function () {
            
            var conn = $.connection();
            var img1 = "online.png";
            var img2 = "offline.png";
            $('#message').keypress(function (event) {
                //javascript keycode 13 == enter 
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });

            conn.received(function (data) {                                       
                $("#message_list").append(data + "<br/>");
                playSound();
                if (data == "Operator is offline now") {
                    $("#Status_div").html("<a href=\"#\" style=\"text-decoration:none;\" title=\"Go To Contact Page\"><img alt=\"offline\" src=\"offline.png\" style=\"border:none;\" /></a>");
                }
                else if (data == "Operator has joined") {                                        
                    location.reload(true);
                    $("#Status_div").html("<img alt=\"online\" src=\"online.png\" />");
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    $("#Status_div").html("<img alt=\"online\" src=\"online.png\" />");
                }
            });         

            conn.start()
            .promise()
            .done(function () {                
                $("#Wait_div").css("visibility", "hidden") 
                $("#send").click(function () {                   
                    if ($("#message").val().length == 0)
                        return;
                    conn.send($("#message").val());
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting a var to your hub and then to start make sure you are using "$.connection.hub". You should also be using ".client.yourmethod" when you reference the var, such as "chat" below uses chat.client.broadcastMessage that the server can call.

```
    var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
    chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
    console.log(name, message);
    };        

    $.connection.hub
    .start()
    .done(function () { })
    .fail(function (error) {
        console.log("An error occurred connecting to the server.");
    });
```